# How can I do an HttpPost using HttpClient to an HTTPS endpoint?

Tags: java, debugging, ssl, httpclient

Whenever I try to post to an https endpoint, I get a javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException :

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;

try {
    MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
    PostMethod pm = new PostMethod("https://www.random.org");
    httpClient.executeMethod(pm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which gives me:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1692)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1675)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1601)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:94)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1565)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at <My File>
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEECPublicKey.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyFactory.createPublicKeyFromPublicKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.initCommon(PKIXValidator.java:92)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:60)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:161)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:204)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:89)
```

I haven't done anything specifically to configure SSL on my machine, but the JSSE test scripts I've run seem to indicate that it's installed. Have I maybe skipped a necessary step? The NullPointerException makes me think that this might be a bug, rather than an expected error.

**EDIT 15 May 2012:**

I've drilled down a bit using the eclipse debugger, to the point where I can see the certs in my SSLSocketFactoryImpl.

```
SchemeSocketFactory socketfac = httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().getScheme("https").getSchemeSocketFactory();
socketfac.socketfactory.context.trustManager.trustedCerts.map.table, in debugger.
```

I can FIND the cert for the site that I'm trying to hit; the thing is, along the way, there's a null pointer exception in the table. (See attached images.) If I use the debugger to remove the 2 (of 183) entries in my entry set which produce an NPE, my code runs perfectly well, but this doesn't seem like a workable solution. I don't think it's an issue with my keystore itself - if I use `keytool -list -keystore cacerts`, It outputs 183 entries, and each of them seems to be formatted appropriately.

---

[image: Table NPE]

---

[image: Table Good Entry]

---

[image: Table BAD Entry]

Comment: Be careful, you're using an obsolete commons-httpclient library. You should now use the new HttpComponents libraries http://hc.apache.org/

Comment: Any reason you're using the BouncyCastle provider for this?

Comment: @Bruno: I'm running the code as part of a larger Tomcat service, and... that's what it defaulted to? How could I use a different provider?

Comment: I'm just surprised to see those bouncycastle traces in your exception. I'd expect it comes from some part of your application adding BC as a security provider at the top of the list via `Security.insertProviderAt(..., 0)` or higher up in the list [in the JRE configuration](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation). I'm also surprised it's trying to instantiate a `JCEECPublicKey` (EC), where the public key is RSA. Which version of the BC library are you using?

Comment: @Bruno: Added a bunch more information from the debugger. I appear to be pulling BC in as part of a Maven dependency, which is being used elsewhere. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15/133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to tease out an answer. I was including bouncycastle version 133 using Maven as part of another artifact required by a separate part of the project. My solution was to upgrade bouncycastle's versionId to 140 in my maven pom.xml file.

Comment: I hadn't realised you'd fixed your problem. Version 140 is [still quite old](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Bouncy-Castle-Crypto-Provider-Package-version-1-40-now-available-td1468420.html), I'd consider a more recent version.

Comment: You're right. I performed a further upgrade to com.bouncycastle 1.46, based on your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Version [133 is about 6 years old](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Bouncy-Castle-Crypto-Provider-Package-version-1-33-now-available-td1468415.html). There have been [a number of fixes since](http://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html). The latest release is 1.47, available under the [`org.bouncycaste` group ID (no longer `bouncycastle`)](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.bouncycastle%22). If you check the release notes, there are a number of bug fixes that were causing `NullPointerException`s.

I also suspect some code is using the BouncyCastle provider instead of the Sun provider when it shouldn't need to, either explicitly or because the BC provider was inserted before the default Sun/Oracle providers using `Security.insertProviderAt(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me. Enable the debug log to see what's going on.

```
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);

  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire", "debug");
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "debug");
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.headers", "debug");
```